# issue with form and controller of an entity that embeds a collection of images in Symfony2 (2.1 branch)

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to resolve this strange problem since last week but I still haven't found any solution so I've decided to ask here.

I'm going to give a brief of my model for better comprehension:

I've a entity called Ruta and it has a collection of images. Every image in Ruta is called ImagenRuta and it has some attributes, including the entity Ruta that owns the ImagenRuta. (OneToManyRelationship)

You can see my entity Ruta here: https://gist.github.com/b0ae0daeaebe4b6323d0

And my entity ImagenRuta here:  https://gist.github.com/9064fb2b5f4138423471

My problem is that I can't update any Ruta from the Controller without lose information about items in the collection of ImagenRuta that the Ruta has. In particular the attribute “imagen” of ImagenRuta is set to null. Other attributes (like ImagenRuta's id or  Ruta's id) are not lost.

I think the problem might be connected with the type file of “imagen” in ImagenRuta's form. Because if I set that field as text the attribute “imagen” of entity ImagenRuta is not lost in any ImagenRuta of the collection that the Ruta I want to update has.

Here is my ImagenRuta's form : https://gist.github.com/0409c630b8c9b3b08068

and my Ruta's form: http://gist.github.com/74db6231a2b238995fff

And here is the code that I wrote to notice the text field issue:

```
class ImagenRutaType extends AbstractType {        
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {          
        $builder->add('imagen', 'text', array('required' => true));    
    }        
}
```

I use the sentences below to restore the original ImagenRuta collection in entity Ruta before modify that entity with form's information by execute `$form->bindRequest($request)` :

```
$anterior = $editForm->getData(); // get ruta entity in form    
$originalImages = $anterior->getImagenes(); // get ImagenRuta collection
```

and then I merge $originalImages  with  the collection of ImagenRuta that $editForm contains

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('RutasBundle:Ruta')->find($id);    
$editForm = $this->createForm(new RutaType(), $entity);    
$editForm->bind($request);    
$imagenesNuevas = $entity->getImagenes()    
// Merge $imagenesNuevas with $originalImages to not to lose any image
```

The problem  is that I can't restore the previous collection of ImagenRuta that the Ruta had, because when I execute:

```
$originalImages  = $ anterior-> getImagenes()
```

in `$originalImages` I have the collection, yes, but all ImagenRuta in that collection has the “imagen” field set to null (others not) and I don't know why.  As I said above, I think it can be related with the field “imagen” in  ImagenRuta's form  is of type 'file' because when this happens every imagenRuta I don't modify from the form comes to the controller with “imagen” field set to null.

Please, see the updateAction in my controller for more detailed information: https://gist.github.com/46e6d0d2f9e188f44030

I have read lots of tutorials, blogs, forums and official cookbook documentation but I haven't found any solution. I hope somebody can help me.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a single property of your entity to hold both the value of the image that is persisted to the database and the file object that is uploaded in your  form. You should have two different properties, one which is persisted to the database and which holds your image filename or path and another property which is not persisted and which will be used for your form file field. Please see this cookbook entry for more information:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html